# ExhaustMap - Refactor - @deprecated resultSelector is no longer supported. Use inner map instead

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

I have this function and VS Code is warning me with this message
**@deprecated — resultSelector is no longer supported. Use inner map instead.**
Reading the RXJS documentation it says **same behavior can be reproduced with the map operator, therefore this argument became deprecated.**

Could someone help me transform it using Map (I don't understand how to do it).

```
exhaustMap((data: [any, Language]) => {
  if (data[0].type === 'mail') {
    return this.authServices.loginEmail(data[0]).pipe(
      map(
        (response: any) =>
          new AuthAct.LoginRedirect({
            url: environment.domainUrl + response.code
          })
      ),
      catchError(error => {
        this.notificationsService.handleError({
          error_key: 'login_error_message',
          info: error
        });
        return of(new AuthAct.ResetLoads());
      })
    );
  } else {
```

—}